# Setting a lookup function to return values even when the condition is not met

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was wondering if it is possible to have a Lookup function that populates the textbox even when the condition is not met?

In the following example, assume that a table is bound to a dataset("TeamTasks") that includes a field for the identifier RelatedProject. A separate dataset called "TeamProjects" contains the corresponding Project and the Project name Title. In the following expression, Lookup compares the value of RelatedProject to (Project)Title in each row of the dataset called "TeamProjects" and, when a match is found, returns the value of the Name field(Title) for that row.

```
=lookUp(Fields!Related_Project.Value, Fields!Title.Value, Fields!Title.Value, "TeamProjects")
```

My question is, is it possible to retrieve the Project title even when the condition is not met. I.e. when there is no task with a relatedproject identifier. Ideally it would still return the project title and have its linked task coming in as Null. It is important for me to have no values left out and I'm not sure what other way I could accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have more than two projects, How do you know a task without related project belongs to a specific project?

Comment: I guess you don't. I just need to retrieve all the values stored in that dataset regardless if there is a related task. If there is, great and it can link up correctly, if not then is it possible to still retrieve the ProjectTitle value and put it in its own row with the related tasks as null.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, I'd invert the lookup direction, i.e set the tablix to `TeamProjects` and lookup related Tasks if any.

Comment: I actually initially started with that and reversed the order to give each task its own row (it is my understanding that when your using the LookupSet function you cant give each of the returned values their own row, which would be ideal)

Comment: `LookupSet` works exactly the same way `LookUp`  it needs a common field to retrieve information from other dataset, the only difference is it returns multiple values in an array, i.e. if a task belongs two different project it will return an array with both titles, (ProjectTitle 1, ProjectTitle 2).

Comment: Yeah, the way it is currently set up in the example above, there is never more than 1 project retrieved per task (just the Lookup function will suffice), whereas if i reversed it, I would need the lookupset function as there is many tasks (and sometimes none - the big problem) , each which need there own row. Thank you by the way!

Comment: Is it impossible for you handle it at SQL level using a LEFT JOIN? If so maybe you can use `Join` function to convert the returned array from LookupSet in a string with information about each task. If that sounds something that could work for you add sample of both datasets and the expected tablix.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how to use SQL within SSRS, any links? haha. But I will look into it!  Thanks again!

Comment: You will need some basic concepts about SQL before but these links could help you, [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627503(v=sql.100).aspx) and [an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/765865/SSRS-Creating-Datasets-Example)